# Error in generated values.xml

Tags: android, xml, gradle

I can't get my Android project to build any more. The first error comes up in a file located at `PATH_TO_PROJECT/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values/values.xml` and the error reads `Error:(2251, 58) String types not allowed (at 'android:id' with value '').` That line is

```
<style name="Platform.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat" parent=""/>
```

But in the file, the line that has red text indicating an error is the first line after the `<?ml` line

```
<resources xmlns:ns1="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
```

with the part in quotes being red.

I also have a problem with my classes suddenly showing errors using `R.id` or `R.menu` or `R.`whatever, though I'm sure that's something that is a side result of the above issue.

I thought it might be that gradle was updated, but I haven't made any changes to the gradle app file, just updated from `2.2.0` to `2.2.2`, would that have caused it?

Comment: The R.* code errors are due to the project not generating the R.java files due to the build errors you are running into.  This should just "work" once you resolve the underlying issues described above.

You have said that the project no longer builds, so at some point it did.  Can you revert any recent changes to see what may have caused this?

Comment: @Zach I figured that was the case for the R.* code. I've been playing around with it all day. I found the specific commit where things start breaking, though I still haven't been able to narrow it down. It is at a branch merging back in, so there are a lot of files that are marked as changed, though the code right before the merge should be identical to after the merge.